# JavaScript not calculating correctly

Tags: javascript

I just started studying JavaScrpt and tried to make code to calculate math formula but it doesn't work as I expected. Here's the code I'm working on. When I run the code if I type 2 in A 3 in B and 4 in C by the formula B^2 - 4 * A * C it should return -23 but it returns -31. Can someone more experienced take a look and tell me where is my mistake?

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="reshenie" action="">
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label for="A">a</label>
        <input id="A" name="A" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="B">b</label>
        <input id="B" name="B" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="C">c</label>
        <input id="C" name="C" type="number" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="reset" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="result">result</label>
        <input id="result" name="result" type="number" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>


  <script>

    (function () {
 function presmqtane(A,B,C) {
  A = parseFloat(A);
  B = parseFloat(B);
  C = parseFloat(C);
 return (B^2 - 4 * A * C);
 }

 var reshenie = document.getElementById("reshenie");
 if (reshenie) {
  reshenie.onsubmit = function () {
   this.result.value = presmqtane(this.A.value, this.B.value, this.C.value);
   return false;
  };
 }

    }());

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `^` is not exponentiation.

Comment: You're looking for `Math.pow()` for exponents: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm guessing that when you wrote this:

```
return (B^2 - 4 * A * C);
```

You meant this:

```
return (Math.pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C);
```

The `^` symbol is the `XOR` operator, not the exponentiation. There is no symbol for that, only `Math.pow()`.

Also note that variable names, in Javascript, are usually written un lower-case. I would use `a`, `b`, `c` instead of `A`, `B`, `C` (which traditionally represent classes, not objects). This also plays along with the mathematical standard (I'm assuming that's the quadratic closed equation), where upper-case letters usually represent objects more complex than numbers, such as matrices or graphs.

Comment: There is a symbol for exponentiation in coming-up ECMAScript versions: `**`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as you want:

```
return (Math.pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C);
```